# How do I obtain an array of counts in perl which includes zeros for keys which had zero count?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, key, key-value

I'd gladly appreciate some advice on this problem I am having with perl.

If I have an array and it contains for example the following integers:

```
1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1
```

once I have computed counts of keys using a hash, the key to value pairs will be:

```
1 => 9, 2 => 1, 3 => 1, 4 => 1, 7 => 1
```

I can assign both sets of numbers (keys and values) to different arrays to use them later, however if I now want an array which looks like this: `(9, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)` with the values in positions corresponding to the keys, with `0`'s for keys which did not appear in the list, namely `5` and `6`, how would i code this in perl?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use List::Util qw( max );

my @a = (1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1);

my %counts;
++$counts{$_} for @a;

my @counts = map $counts{$_} // 0, 1..max(keys(%counts));
```

Comment: Thanks ikegami! That works a treat - but say if my data is not comma separated and instead i am reading the data in from a text file which contains a column of data using $filename = $ARGV[0];
open(FILE, $filename); my @a = <FILE>; ... then the above code does not seem to work. why is that?

Comment: You used the word columns, so that lead me to believe you might need something closer to `while (<FILE>) { chomp; my @a = split; ... }`. Hard to tell without really knowing what the file is like.

Comment: The initial file was a column of names pasted into a text file, working on Windows. This was subsequently passed through a counting script using my @array=<FILE>; my %count; map{$count{$_}++ @array; print "$count{$_}\n" foreach keys %count; which gave me a column of numbers - I then wanted to take that output and convert to the column/array of values/frequencies which was my inital question. i hope that makes it clearer

Comment: hi ikegami - i managed it in the end using a while loop! thank you so much for your help!

Comment: while (my $line=<FILE>)
{chomp ($line);
push (@array,$line);
} - is there a more succinct way to do this?

Comment: `chomp( my @array = <FILE> );`

Answer (score 0):

Easily:

```
my @counts = map { $_ || 0 } @hash{ 1 .. 7 };
```

We slice the hash using the numbers from 1 to 7.  `undef` is returned for keys that do not have corresponding values, so the `map` turns all Boolean-false values into zeroes.

Comment: i seem to get the error global symbol "%hash" requires explicit package name, having exchanged the last line of the above code for this line, but instead of 7 i've exchanged that for $maxkey, which i defined as the max of the array of keys.